# UIWebView content size

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, interface-builder, contentsize

I'm working on an app that can retrieve images from the web.  Rather than actually download the images, I'm trying to display them in a UIWebView.  I really need the images to be a specific size on my screen, so I have made a webview of the size I need, and told it to scalesPageToFit, but when I run, the image is not the correct size within the view.  I am using a 1024x768 image as a test, and have tried numerous iterations of view sizes to get it correct on my screen, but I either end up with an illogical size, or it clips.

Here is the original image; http://www.coolopticalillusions.com/backgrounds/freaky-desktop-background-7.jpg

I am trying to make the image 300 wide, which preserving aspect ratio, would mean the view should be 245 high.

This first screenshot is with a 300x245 UIWebView, you can see the width is correct, but the height is not, the red box should be aligned exactly with the bottom of the image 
http://img839.imageshack.us/f/sizecropped.png/

This second screenshot is with a 300x300, which scales the image too wide for the view, and also too high as well.
http://img155.imageshack.us/f/sizetoobig.png/

I have been struggling for a while trying to get this to do what I want it to, but I am just not having any success whatsoever.

EDIT: The only relevant code I have is this:

```
NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.coolopticalillusions.com/backgrounds/freaky-desktop-background-7.jpg"];
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[messageView.imageWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
messageView.imageWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the webview first with the application frame as frame. Then you can add your image to a new imageview which has your size (300x245). Add the image to the webview as subview.

```
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    // get image from web
    id path = @"http://www.coolopticalillusions.com/backgrounds/freaky-desktop-background-7.jpg";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];

    // create new image view with your prefered size
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 245);

    // add image view to your webview
    [webView addSubview:imageView];
```

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: How do I get the image out of the webview?  That seems much easier than what I'm trying to do if I can just do that then

Comment: You can get an UIImage by its url: id path = @"http://www.coolopticalillusions.com/backgrounds/freaky-desktop-background-7.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];

Comment: Wow that is amazingly easy, I wish I knew about that feature sooner, now I can just use the image view rather than complicating it with the webview.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Adding the image view as a subview is not the same as loading it in the webView. In this example, the webView might as well be a plain UIView.